# How to get SOAP XML request / response documents in Spring WS?

Tags: xml, spring, soap, spring-ws

I need to get `XML` documents that are sent and received in my Spring WS application. Application send `SOAP` request to to the server (document one) and receive a response (document two) and I need to save these documents for later displaying in my administration system.

Is there some way how to catch these documents ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an Endpoint interceptor class by implementing `EndpointInterceptor` interface. This has methods to handle the Requests/Response/Faults. This way you can capture all the request & response XMLs and process it however you want.

Make sure you define the beans correctly.

```html
<bean id="rootEndpointMapping"
  class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping">
 <property name="interceptors">
  <list>
   <ref bean="commonInterceptor" />
  </list>
 </property>
</bean>

<bean id="commonInterceptor" class="com.foo.Xyz" />

<bean id="messageReceiver"
  class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.SoapMessageDispatcher">
 <property name="endpointMappings">
  <list>
   <ref bean="rootEndpointMapping" />
  </list>
 </property>
 <property name="endpointAdapters">
  ...
 </property>
</bean>
```